# Assign value to parent form in asp ModalPopupExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I'm developing an application where in I'm using ModalPopUpExtender and in iFrame of ModalPopUpExtender I'm embedding another aspx page, like in a code below. Now what i want to do is I want the value of text box from the embedded aspx form on the parent aspx page. Please help me out.

```
                                <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">


                                    <iframe style=" width: 90%; height: 380px;" id="irm1" src="CityMaster.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
                                        <br/>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button4" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Close"/>
                                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `UserControl` instead of the iframe? Then you could provide a property in the `UserControl` which returns the `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: what is the id of the text box ? you can access the same in your codebehind

Comment: @TimSchmelter : The form is having multiple controls and also they are getting dynamically generated. So I preferred to use form

Comment: you need javascript for that , from iframe to access parent use window.top , from parent to access iframe use document.frames[0]

Comment: @ArunChandranC : textbox id is txtVal, It can be accessed in child form but not in parent form.

Comment: @Omkar: that's not a reason to use an iframe + aspx-page. You can do that also with a `UserControl`(ascx) which is also more reusable. It's just a container for your controls.

Comment: @TimSchmelter , your solution is more robust one , how to close this one...?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue is solved by a different approach (using a UserControl).

Comment: @vishalsharma: now i've voted to close since i thought that you were the OP. You could provide an answer with your approach and mention the UserControl approach if you want.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : You've added a new solution of using UserControl, till now I didn't used any user control in my application. But now I'll kook forward to use in my application to increase re usability Thanks a lot for the suggestion. And I hope same help in further user control development from your side. Again thanks a lot. :)